# If there were infinite many stars

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, astrophysics, universe

If there were infinite many stars, is the sky then always full of light so is there than even night?

Comment: That's called [Olber's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers'_paradox).

Comment: This is well covered already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF there were infinite stars(or a lot of stars) the fact that the night sky is dark indicates that there was not enough time for light from those stars to travel to us. That means the stars started to radiate light at a finite time before.

Comment: Or, alternately, the stars are receding so quickly that their light has been redshifted to below the visible spectrum.